# Digital Signature for Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

We have purchased the google maps license and wanted to use the Gecoding API web service to generate the Lat and Long for the given address. I would like to know do i need to generate the Private key for each and every given address or i can generate a private key once and use it for all the address and generate the lat and long.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can generate just once... check the google API documentation for more information:

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth